# SSRS - How To Display Top N on Column chart

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a column chart that has 40+ categories, what I want to accomplish is to display the top N on the column chart and combine the rest of the categories as "Other Category" so that it will fit in the column chart. I can set-up the top N in the filter properties of the data set, but I can't figure out how to combine the categories after the top 12.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the other categories if you add another field where you combine them, in a calculated field for example. Go to datasets (left on the report) and **Right click on your dataset > Field properties > Fields > Add > Calculated Field**. Now enter a field name (for example **CategoriesUnder12**) and in the expression write something like

```
=IFF(Fields!Categorie.Value = "Sales" OrElse Fields!Categorie.Value = "Marketing", "CombindedCategories", Fields!Categorie.Value)
'Everything you want to combine comes in the OrElse clause
```

Now you have all categories unter 12 combined in the categorie name **CombindedCategories**. If you group your chart now after **CategoriesUnder12** you have the 12 top with their categorie names and everything below combined.